# how do I connect cloud function to cloud composer without vpc connector?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-composer

I am using cloud function to trigger the cloud composer for data workflow using a vpc connector in between. I want to reduce the cost of using vpc connector which requires minimum 2 instances. what is the alternative setup we can use to connect these two services privately ?

I am looking for an alternative to serverless vpc connector.

Comment: Why do you need a VPC in between ? If you run your cloud function and trigger a DAG in Composer via an API call (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf), it should work.

Comment: @DevYns Thanks, lets see I have to check on this